# General solution for "figure margins too large"

Tags: r, plot

This is a "classic" problem with base graphics in R: "figure margins too large" error appears in base graphics when displaying different plots. The problem appears multiple times on SO and on the web.

There are different workarounds:

- save the plot as a file (e.g. with `png`)
- change the margins manually
- change dimensions of window that displays the plot
- resize the window manually

However, those are not general solutions. Some of them are OS specific, some are specific for a certain IDE you use etc. However I am interested in the "just fit it into the screen you have" solution for this problem. Is there any?

Is there a *general* workaround for this? Could it be dealt in automatic way? It does not seem that complicated problem to have no general solution...

**EDIT:**

@BenBolker asked for a reproducible example, here is one:

```
par(mfrow=c(k, k))
for (i in 1:k)
  hist(dnorm(100))
```

Where `k` is e.g. 5, 10 etc.

Comment: The general solution is to have a large enough canvas, e.g. use `png()` (or your favourite device) that is large enough to fit the plot, given the standard margins.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want a solution for displaying the plot not for saving it.

Comment: Which operating system?  On windows use `windows(widht, height`) and AFAIK `x11()` does something similar on linux and mac.  In an IDE, make your graphics window large enough.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes, however as you can see those are not general but rather a problem-specific solutions. So my question is: is there a general solution? Some: "just fit it into the screen you have". I work both on linux and on windows, both on Rstudio server and on a local computer. I *know* the "local" solutions but find them inconvenient as I work in different environments sometimes at the same time.

Comment: I suggest you add all that information, your previous research and background knowledge into your question.

Comment: maybe you could post a (generally) reproducible example?  I can imagine that there might be something with reducing `cex` ...

Comment: `dev.new` opens a new graphics device, and you can specify `hieght` and `width`, and it works for any setup. You can use that to make a "big enough" canvas no matter what system you are working under.

Comment: it does look adjusting `par("cex")` could help.  You could write a `while(try())` loop to try to find the largest value that will work.

Comment: @BrianDiggs however this needs choosing some arbitrary large values for those parameters and it needs you to adjust all the other parameters (e.g. `cex`). My argument is: it is possible with `ggplot`, it is possible if you plot to a file, so why it seems that complicated for printing (with base graphics) on the screen?